# What is the units digit of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{1337} (n!)^4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, factorial

What is the units digit of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{1337}(n!)^4$ ?
I find 9 but I am not sure.

Comment: HINT: After $n=5$, $n!$ ends with a zero.

Comment: $9$ is correct; how did you arrive at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

In mod $10$ we have $n!=0$ for $n\ge5$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $9$ is correct because from $n = 5$ and up, the units digit will always be zero, so sum up $n!$ from $0$ to $4$. And you have:

$$
\begin{align}
(1!)^4 & = 1\times1\times1\times1 = 1 \\
(2!)^4 & = 2\times2\times2\times2 = 16 \\
(3!)^4 & = 6\times6\times6\times6 = \dots6 \impliedby {6^n}\mod10 = 6,n\in \mathbb{N}\\
(4!)^4 & = 24\times24\times24\times24 = \dots6 \impliedby 4^{2n}\mod10=6,n\in \mathbb{N}\\
(5!)^4 & = 120\times120\times120\times120 = \dots0\\
\vdots
\end{align}
$$
So adding up the unit digits:

$$1+6+6+6 = 19$$

So the unit digit of $\sum\limits^{1337}_{n=1} \left(n!\right)^4$ is $9$

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider $\pmod{10}$. What is $5! \pmod{10}$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that after $5!$ the last digit will be a zero. 
So for the first four terms:

$= (1!^4)+(2!^4)+(3!^4)+(4!^4)+(5!^4)...(1337!^4)$

$=1+6+6+6+0+0... $ (Only the last digits)

Therefore it is 9.